# How to take integer from an string value which is stored in a method/function?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, buddypress

In buddypress plugin subject is printed using this code

```
<?php bp_the_thread_subject(); ?>
```

at my end this function/method is printing result like Hello world: 1236 . I want to take only integer value from this. But when i am applying anything to this function/method, it is getting zero result. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function to extract the number

```
<?php
    function bp_the_thread_subject(){
        //All your logic to return the string....

        return 'Hello world: 1236';
    }

    $value = filter_var(bp_the_thread_subject(), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    echo $value // 1236;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `bp_the_thread_subject()` returns `Hello world: 1236`, when can use `filter_var`  with `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` to remove everything that's not an `int`.

```
$identity  = filter_var( bp_the_thread_subject(), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
$myInt = (int)$identity;
var_dump($myInt);
//int(1236)
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/luiEWy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` to return only the number:

```
<?php preg_match('/\d+/', bp_the_thread_subject(), $matches)[1] ?>
```